# Adding vertical space after custom environment, excluding last in the surrounding environment

Tags: environments, vspace

I am fairly new to LaTeX, so please excuse my ignorance.

Here is a portion of my source. You will notice that I use `\vspace` between `_history` environments. I know that I can add `\vspace` to last `{}` of `\newenvironment`, but this means the last `_history` will include the spacing. Is there a way to add `\vspace` to `_history`, for all but the last `_history` within the surrounding environment (`_section` in this case)?

To compare this to CSS, we would do something like:

```css
_section:not(:last-child) {
  ...
}
```

```tex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.4in,top=0.4in,right=0.4in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.4pt}

\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\newenvironment{_section}[1] {
    \noindent
    \textbf{\textsc{#1}}
    \smallskip
    \hrule
    \begin{list}{} { \setlength{\leftmargin}{0em} }
    \item[]
}{  \end{list}}

\newenvironment{_history}[5] {
    \StrLen{#2}[\argTwoLen]
    \StrLen{#4}[\argFourLen]
    \textbf{#1}\ifthenelse{\argTwoLen > 0}{, #2}{}\hfill#3
    \ifthenelse{\argFourLen > 0}{\\\textit{#4}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{TRUE}}{\vspace{4pt}\\}{}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{_section}{Technical Experience}
    \begin{_history}{Perthera, Inc.}{Holliston MA}{05/2020 -- 08/2020}{Software Developer Intern}{FALSE}
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
            \item Software development with \uline{Java}---backend \uline{RESTful APIs} and frontend UI.
            \item Individually rewrote an entire application’s frontend with \uline{Vaadin} 8 and some backend.
            \item Individually updated projects with Ant/Ivy build systems to \uline{Maven}.
            \item Programmed interoperability between databases of different forms. I.e., importing data from one model to another, with a mix of \uline{Java} and \uline{SQL}. Used \uline{JSON} for input parameters and output.
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
                \item For example, I wrote a \uline{RESTful API} to match data between a \uline{SQL} database and HubSpot with a confidence algorithm, import some into HubSpot, or update the database.
            \end{itemize}
            \item Used \uline{SQL} and MySQL with triggers and views.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{_history}
    \vspace{2pt}
    \begin{_history}{Massachusetts Bay Community College}{Wellesley MA}{01/2020 -- 05/2020}{Peer Tutor \& Embedded Tutor}{FALSE}
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
            \item Tutored students enrolled in Programming I and Basic Math through Calculus I.
            \item Acted as a resource and guide to students struggling academically.
            \item In-class tutor for Programming I labs.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{_history}
    \vspace{2pt}
    \begin{_history}{ALARM Robotics}{Franklin MA}{12/2019 -- Present}{Software Development Mentor}{TRUE}
        ALARM Robotics is a registered team in the FIRST Robotics Competition. Teams of high school students and adult mentors have six weeks to build a competitive robot.
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
            \item Mentored high school students interested in programming.
            \item Introduced programming concepts to mentees, such as \uline{Object-Oriented Programming}, \uline{Data Structures}, API usage, and basic embedded software design, with \uline{Java}.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{_history}
\end{_section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I  know no way, but in my opinion, it's simpler to add it to the environments, and remove it manually  to the last only.

Comment: @Bernard Did you mean "I know **a** way"?

Comment: No, I meant I have no way in mind. But you might have a boolean optional argument for the environment, which would remove this spacing  only if set to true.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you. I did consider this, but, as you can see, I did this for some other elements and it seems messy to me. Coming from a programming background, with languages that allow default parameter values or function overloading, that is.

Comment: You might take a look at the very useful  `xparse` package possibilities (and `etoolbox` for its way to manage boolean flags).

Comment: @Bernard Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the skip length as an optional argument to `_history` with a default of (based on your code) `2pt`.  On the last invocation, pass `[0pt]` as the optional argument.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.4in,top=0.4in,right=0.4in,bottom=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.4pt}

\setmainfont{Palatino Linotype}

\newenvironment{_section}[1] {
    \noindent
    \textbf{\textsc{#1}}
    \smallskip
    \hrule
    \begin{list}{} { \setlength{\leftmargin}{0em} }
    \item[]
}{  \end{list}}

\newlength\interhistory

\newenvironment{_history}[6][2pt] {%
    \setlength\interhistory{#1}%
    \StrLen{#3}[\argTwoLen]
    \StrLen{#5}[\argFourLen]
    \textbf{#2}\ifthenelse{\argTwoLen > 0}{, #3}{}\hfill#4
    \ifthenelse{\argFourLen > 0}{\\\textit{#5}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{TRUE}}{\vspace{4pt}\\}{}
}{\vspace{\interhistory}}

\begin{document}

\begin{_section}{Technical Experience}
    \begin{_history}{Perthera, Inc.}{Holliston MA}{05/2020 -- 08/2020}{Software Developer Intern}{FALSE}
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
            \item Software development with \uline{Java}---backend \uline{RESTful APIs} and frontend UI.
            \item Individually rewrote an entire application’s frontend with \uline{Vaadin} 8 and some backend.
            \item Individually updated projects with Ant/Ivy build systems to \uline{Maven}.
            \item Programmed interoperability between databases of different forms. I.e., importing data from one model to another, with a mix of \uline{Java} and \uline{SQL}. Used \uline{JSON} for input parameters and output.
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
                \item For example, I wrote a \uline{RESTful API} to match data between a \uline{SQL} database and HubSpot with a confidence algorithm, import some into HubSpot, or update the database.
            \end{itemize}
            \item Used \uline{SQL} and MySQL with triggers and views.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{_history}
    \begin{_history}{Massachusetts Bay Community College}{Wellesley MA}{01/2020 -- 05/2020}{Peer Tutor \& Embedded Tutor}{FALSE}
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
            \item Tutored students enrolled in Programming I and Basic Math through Calculus I.
            \item Acted as a resource and guide to students struggling academically.
            \item In-class tutor for Programming I labs.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{_history}
    \begin{_history}[0pt]{ALARM Robotics}{Franklin MA}{12/2019 -- Present}{Software Development Mentor}{TRUE}
        ALARM Robotics is a registered team in the FIRST Robotics Competition. Teams of high school students and adult mentors have six weeks to build a competitive robot.
        \begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
            \item Mentored high school students interested in programming.
            \item Introduced programming concepts to mentees, such as \uline{Object-Oriented Programming}, \uline{Data Structures}, API usage, and basic embedded software design, with \uline{Java}.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{_history}
\end{_section}
Blah-blah

\end{document}
```

[image]